# Podio API - Invalid token during project tasks sync

Tags: podio

We're currently receiving this 400 error when trying to fetch new tasks:

```
{"error_parameters":{},"error_detail":null,"error_propagate":false,"request":{"url":"http:\/\/api.podio.com\/task","query_string":"completed=true&completed_on=-5d&fields=completed_on&limit=100&offset=0&sort_by=rank&sort_desc=false&space=3798819","method":"GET"},"error_description":"Invalid token '(files,tags,votes)'","error":"invalid_value"}
```

Just so you know we don't use this for our internal purposes, instead we have an integration set up that allows tasks sync'ing and completion.

We're doing a loop to paginate through all the space tasks:

`get('/task', { space: project_link.remote_id, sort_by: 'rank', limit: limit, offset: offset, sort_desc: false, completed: completed, fields: 'completed_on' })`

**EDIT:**

```
def sync_project(project_link)
  existing_remote_ids = _synced_remote_task_ids(project_link.link_id)
  synced_project_ids = []
  [{completed: false}, {completed: true}].each do |params|
    offset = 0
    loop do
      tasks, next_offset = tasks_page_for_project(project_link: project_link, offset: offset, **params)
      tasks.each do |task|
        remote_task = map_podio_task(task, project_link.link_id)
        _process_task(remote_task)
        synced_project_ids << remote_task[:id].to_s
      end
      offset = next_offset
      break unless next_offset
    end
  end
  _mark_tasks_deleted(existing_remote_ids - synced_project_ids)
end

def tasks_page_for_project(project_link:, offset:, completed: false)
  next_offset = nil
  limit = 100
  params = { space: project_link.remote_id, sort_by: 'rank', limit: limit, offset: offset, sort_desc: false, completed: completed, fields: 'completed_on' }
  params[:completed_on] = '-5d' if completed
  tasks = get('/task', params)
  if tasks.size == limit
    next_offset = offset + limit
  end
  return tasks, next_offset
rescue TaskSync::ProjectRemovedError => ex
  raise TaskSync::ProjectRemovedError.new(self, project_link.remote_id), ex.message
rescue TaskSync::TemporaryNetworkError => ex
  ex.project_id = project_link.remote_id
  raise ex
end

def service
  check_token
  @service ||= build_client(href, 'Authorization' => "OAuth2 #{token[:token]}")
end

def authorization
  params = {
    grant_type: 'refresh_token',
    client_id: TaskSync.config[:podio][:client_id],
    client_secret: TaskSync.config[:podio][:client_secret],
    refresh_token: token[:refresh_token]
  }

  build_client 'https://podio.com/oauth/token', { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }, params
end

def href
  'https://api.podio.com'
end
```

And this error only occurs for a single client.

Can you tell us what this error means? Is it OAuth related or does it have to do with something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide code sample, so I try to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Edited with the largest part of the integration. The response is simply parsed through a `JSON.parse(respone.body)` and depending on the status code we either return it or we raise the appropriate error.

Comment: Thanks for sample. This seems to be not related to oAuth, but rather to details how tasks are retrieved. Can you please try one possible fix: replace '-5d' with '5_days' or other available options from here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/tasks/get-tasks-77949 (And one more possible fix: add 'files:false' to list of params)

Comment: Thanks @Pavlo-Podio! I'll try that and get back to you in a couple of days and see if it still happens.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio sorry, a lot of other bugs and features got in the way. I'll see if I can tackle it the next week.

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio 5_days can not be used with the completed_on filter (yields the error "The values are not in the right format").  the 5_days, etc.. are for grouping which we are not doing..  We are filtering.. AND the filtering just plain doesn't work either..  filtering with completed_on=-5d simply returns all completed tasks.

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio any other suggestions?

Comment: It looks like a bug in Podio API, please raise support ticket (and mention me there, so we can handle it through Podio support). To raise a ticket, please mail to support@podio.com

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting spotted issue in Podio documentation.  It was misleading here (updated docs are already published).

Format for `completed_on` field is `YYYY-MM-DD-YYYY-MM-DD`.
E.g. for all tasks completed in Jun 2017: `2017-06-01-2017-06-30`

Comment: Are you sure??  As this error only occurred randomly and I do not believe it had anything to do with the format of the completed_on..    And you have stated there are no less than 3 different styles of syntax for this..   It comes across very much so that you do not know how your API even works.  It also would be VERY BAD to change the API contract randomly and not support older syntax (-5d)..  if we are receiving errors then it is an issue with your API not working correctly.

Comment: This question is now answered and answer accepted. Podio did NOT change API randomly, but there was a misleading documentation for date format for task related operation which was fixed 3 month ago. @Urkle - if you have similar question/issue - please ask new question on SO :)

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio after implementing this, I thought of a few cases that we need to know before deploying the change:

1. What timezone do you interpret the completed_on filter in?
2. Do you by any chance support open ended filters (equivalent to >=)? (e.g. "2017-10-13-" )
3. Can we just do a filter +2 days from now (e.g. "2017-10-13-2017-10-20") to account for any timezone oddities?

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio ping.

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio yes, I implemented it and it works for most cases, but we want to make sure we've covered everything so we don't have customers missing tasks from their projects during a sync. That's why I asked the questions above.

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio ping.

Comment: Well, I mean, have you tried open ended filters (equivalent to >=)? (e.g. "2017-10-13-" ) ? I know that Podio doesn't support them, but it's better if you try and see result yourself :)

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio the open ended filter seems to work. So in what timezone do you interpret the completed on filter?

Answer (score -2):

you did not mention what programming language you are using here is an example I wrote on PHP :

```
require_once 'podio/PodioAPI.php'; //podio library

error_log("validate triggerd");

$client_id = 'your client Id';
$client_secret = 'your client secret';
$app_id = 'your app id';
$app_token = 'your app token';

Podio::setup($client_id, $client_secret);
// Turn on debugging
Podio::$debug = true;

// Authenticate the app
Podio::authenticate('app', array('app_id' => $app_id, 'app_token' => $app_token));
```

and get your item:

```
$tasks = PodioTask::get_all( $attributes = array() );
```

Comment: We are using ruby and the problem is not how to make the request, but what that error actually means. I added the `ruby` tag to the question even though that shouldn't make a difference.